# Angular Visual Studio Code debugger not hitting Breakpoints

Tags: angular, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, debugging, breakpoints

I haven't used VS Code for developing Angular for a while (~ 2 months).
Debugging with Chrome has always been working and Breakpoints were hit and hovering over variables showed me their runtime values.

Now all of a sudden it just seems to hit some of the Breakpoints that I set but I can't figure out a certain pattern...

[image: BreakpointSample]

The upper Breakpoint will NOT be hit. Only the Breakpoint below.
Even if I set a Breakpoint in line 132 the Breakpoint is automatically set to 133...

My `launch.json` looks like:

```json
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "skipFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
                "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.mjs"
            ]
        }
    ]
```